# Entity Framework calling stored procedure in a loop returning incorrect results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure that returns something similar to this:

> PrevLocationId | PrevLocationName | NextLocationId | NextLocationName
>   | BatchId | ConnectionId

It receives two parameters, the BatchId, and the ConnectionId which are bigint and int respectively.

This stored procedure is being called in a C# app using the very first version of Entity Framework.

Within the app there is a TransactionScope and inside a loop that is going to execute this sproc with different parameters.

I am verifying a defect in the application in which, on my test, the loop runs twice with the following parameters:

> First run: BatchId = 34, ConnectionId = 20
>   Second run: BatchId = 34,
>   ConnectionId = 23

When I set a break point on the sproc call and I execute it directly on the database I get the correct results on both executions, but when I allow the application to execute it **I am always getting the results from the first execution BOTH TIMES.**

I have verified in SQL Profiler that the database is receiving the correct parameters in each execution.

I have tried removing the Transaction Scope with the same results.

Does anybody know if there is some weird caching thing that entity framework does or if there is a glitch on it or something that may be affecting the returned results?

I have no idea where else to look. Any insight would be greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Are you using Linq to Sql to strongly define your stored procedures? Can we see the code you are using to call

Comment: I think EF does cache entities to a certain extent although it does not seem to make sense do do it in this context.  For testing have you tried instantiating and destroying the object context within the loop? This tell you whether it is a caching issue because if it is caching it it is happening in the object context.

Comment: _the very first version of Entity Framework_? Maybe this should be migrated to history.stackexchange.com. No serious, are you stuck to this version? It was not exactly mature.

Comment: @GertArnold: We are stuck with this version until our customer decides to upgrade, which will happen eventually but we still do not know when.

Comment: O boy. I hope you will be able to work around this. Maybe by using a new context for each call, if that doesn't fight the rest of the logic? In the mean time pray each night that the customer will allow an update real soon.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in the first version of Entity Framework the ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction had a merge option default of AppendOnly and you could not set it to anything else.

In that situation there are only two workarounds, that we can think of, to solve this issue:

1. Use Ado .Net to call the stored procedure.
2. Add a Guid as the first parameter of the stored procedure so Entity Framework knows there is always a new call and should not use cached results.

In Entity Framework version 4 the ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction has overloads in which we can set the MergeOption to NoTracking which will solve this kind of issue.